# How can I edit the search form?

Tags: forms, search, 7, distributions

I have an OpenAtrium distribution installed on Drupal 6. As you may already know OpenAtrium already implements a search feature. What I'd like to do is change the following form:

[image]

by adding another button alongside the Search one (there are other modifications that I'd like to do but it doesn't matter this is just the final goal).

The problem is that I don't know what is the PHP page that builds that form. All I know is that page.header.inc prints the content of that form:

```
 ...
 <div id='space-tools'><div class='dropdown-blocks toggle-blocks clear-block'><?php print $space_tools ?></div></div>
 ...
```

As you can imagine $space_tools contains the entire menu and also the form. But who's the one who builds the $space_tools variable? Is there an OpenAtrium API that I can read somewhere?

This is the result HTML which I'd like to change:

```
<div id="space-tools"><div class="dropdown-blocks toggle-blocks clear-block processed">  
<form action="/openatrium/XXXXXX/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="atrium-search-form">
<div>
    <div class="form-item form-item-labeled" id="edit-search-wrapper">
        <label for="edit-search">Search XXXXXXX: <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="search" id="edit-search" value="" class="form-text required fluid">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Search" class="form-submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-31ea0a19166f0619050f7ac923ebf331" value="form-31ea0a19166f0619050f7ac923ebf331">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-atrium-search-form-form-token" value="aaf2e5374720acee5769fcafb6421e35">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-atrium-search-form" value="atrium_search_form">
</div>
</form>
```

Thank you. Almost forgot, here where I work imgur is blocked by the proxy so I can't tell if the image has been uploaded or not.

EDIT: This is driving me crazy I looked up over the entire OpenAtrium folder for the word "atrium-search-form" and no result at all inside files. How can this even be possible lol? Unless the ID is built upon different variables, in that case I don't know what to do...

Comment: The image uploaded fine by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's displayed using the Context module.  I found it like this:

- Go to `admin/build/context` and select the `global` context

  - Click the `Blocks` reaction
  - Under the `Space tools` region, `Atrium: Search form` block is being shown

I then searched for the name `Atrium: Search form`, and found that the block is defined in the `atrium_features` module, in functions `atrium_block` and `atrium_search_form` of file `atrium/atrium.module`.

You could modify the search form using a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` hook, such as `hook_form_atrium_search_form_alter`.

Comment: There was an [issue](https://community.openatrium.com/issues/node/3247) on the Open Atrium community that pointed me to that direction as well. Thank you!